# Fingerprint BiometricPrompt on android P from a View

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics, android-9.0-pie, android-fingerprint-api

I am using `FingerprintManager` to authenticate my app with fingerprint.
I have and android `View` with the fingerprint ui and when the `FingerprintManager.authenticate` callbacks are called I handle the callbacks in the view, e.g change fingerprint icon, error text etc.

Now in Android P, I have to use `BiometricPrompt`, which is easy enough to use, but forces me to have an `Activity` in order to work properly

Is there a way to make `BiometricPrompt` work in a plain android view?

this is my working code to launch the prompt in an activity

```
    Signature signature = createSignature();
    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt.Builder(context)
            .setDescription("Description")
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setSubtitle("Subtitle")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", context.getMainExecutor(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Cancel button clicked");
                }
            })
            .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(signature), cancellationSignal, context.getMainExecutor() , new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {...}
```

where context is an activity that without it it can not work

Comment: _"Now in Android P, I have to use BiometricPrompt"_ Depends on what you mean by _"have to"_; `FingerprintManager` is deprecated, but it's still available, _"where context is an activity"_ I don't see anything in the documentation about it having to be an `Activity` specifically. Looking at the source code for `BiometricPrompt`, all it uses the context for is to call `getSystemService` and `getPackageManager`. Since you already need a `Context` to get a `FingerprintManager`, have you tried just using that same context to create a `BiometricPrompt`?

Comment: Yes, and I have received `onAuthenticationError` automatically. also, when using FingerprintManager in android P, also `onAuthenticationError` is called automatically

the working code of FingerprintManager deployed in production, doesn't work for my users in android P, therefor this question was raised

p.s. I also looked in BiometricPrompt source code and saw plain Context, and not activity. so this is weid for me as well

Comment: _"when using FingerprintManager in android P, also onAuthenticationError is called automatically"_ I've used `FingerprintManager` successfully on both Android P (Galaxy S10) and Android Q Beta (Pixel 3).

Comment: interesting, I'll take a look. can you paste a sample code so I can maybe see the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going over the comments I have received in the question thread, I saw that the problem was in cancellationSignal, `FingerprintManager` does work in Android P as well as `BiometricPrompt` in views,

The actual problem was on Samsung devices (Note9 , S10) running android P,
when using `FingerprintManager` a transparent screen will appear and cover the view
I had `cancelationSignal.cancel` in `onDetach` that would break the entire auth flow. On other devices it makes sense, since the user can close the fingerprint screen on demand

Comment: Hi, @BennyP. Do you have any ideas about how to disable the "transparent screen" popped up by the Samsung devices (S10). My app has its own fingerprint prompt dialog and I don't want the users to see 2 overlapped prompt screens. Thanks!

Comment: there is no way afaik, you can use BiometricPrompt to customize your message to the user